# Vertica Loading data from file to table

Tags: vertica

I want to load data from file to a vertical table. The data I am receiving in file is in format `02-APR-17 11.06.31.000000 AM +00:00` but the data type of column is `timestamp(0)` and the expected format of output is `4/2/2017 12:06:31.000000`

Comment: And what is your attempt at this? Show us what you've done so far.

Comment: i tried this query SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('02-APR-17 11.06.31.000000 AM +00:00','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS.MS AM') AT TIME ZONE 'CST'; the query works fine if the data is already present in the table. but how to while loading from file to table is where i am hung up right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is your table:

```
    CREATE TABLE foo (
      id INT NOT NULL
    , ts TIMESTAMP(0)
    , nm VARCHAR(32)
    );
```

And this is your data:

```
    42;02-APR-17 11.06.31.000000 AM +00:00;Arthur Dent
    43;14-APR-17 11.06.31.000000 PM +00:00;Ford Prefect
    44;15-APR-17 09.06.31.000000 PM +00:00;Zaphod Beeblebrox
```

Then, try this COPY command, where you use FILLER and a derivation:

```
    COPY foo (
      id
    , ts_buf FILLER VARCHAR(40)
    , ts AS TO_TIMESTAMP(ts_buf,'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS.MS AM') AT TIME ZONE 'CST'
    , nm
    )
    FROM '/home/dbadmin/data/foo.txt'
    DELIMITER ';'
    DIRECT
    ;
```

.. and this is the table you get:

```
SELECT * FROM foo;

id|ts                 |nm
42|2017-04-02 11:06:31|Arthur Dent
43|2017-04-14 23:06:31|Ford Prefect
44|2017-04-15 21:06:31|Zaphod Beeblebrox
```

Is this what you were after?

cheers - Marco the Sane